# is it possible to bring in sharepoint image picker in html

Tags: 2013, 2010

I am having a content editor webpart which references to a html file

I have input box for entering the path of the image. It will be saved in webpart properties.

Now is it possible to bring in something like a sharepoint image picker in html?

i.e a `RichImageField`

```
<PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField FieldName="PageImage" runat="server" />
```

The objective is to allow user to browse and pick images from sharepoint publishing images folder

solution need not be a richimageifleld. anything that allows me to browse and pick image is fine

Comment: As per my understanding, this is not possible, if you place this `RIchImageField` into Content Editor Web Part, It will not show the exact code as you are expecting, instead it will consider as static html content and displays it.

Comment: It need not be a richimageifleld.
anything that allows me to browse and pick image is fine

Comment: In that case you need to develop something like it or use any existing plugins to upload images, Refer: http://spimagefieldupload.codeplex.com/